# ¿Hay alguna opción para que una expresión regular encuentre las letras acentuadas en .NET?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

Me explico, quiero que la expresión regular `\w` encuentre los caractéres `[a-zA-Z_0-9áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]` que como sabéis forman parte de lo que es considerado una palabra en el idioma español.

Creía que dependía del locale, pero no es así, ya que aún cambiando el CurrentCulture antes de ejecutar la expresión regular, sigue sin darme los resultados con letras acentuadas.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-ES")
```

También he utilizado la alternativa `\p{L}` con igual resultado.

He mirado en las opciones que se pueden poner al ejecutar expresiones regulares en .NET y hay una que se llama `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant`, pero no me sirve porque está pensada para las comparaciones de cadenas con mayúsculas y minúsculas.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_11

Podría utilizar una expresión ad-hoc `[a-zA-Z_0-9áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]`, pero es más larga, menos legible y además en el futuro quiero soportar más idiomas con lo que tendría que crear una diferente para cada idioma.

Lo que pregunto es si .NET tiene una lista de idiomas con los caracteres que forman parte de una palabra y sólo pasando el locale por ejemplo "es-ES" ya interpretaría `\w` o `\p{L}` como `[a-zA-Z_0-9áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ]`

Comment: Porque no te basta con `p{L}`? No te basta incluir los que sí son o deseas  también excluir los que no son

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que he metido la pata con la pregunta. Funciona perfectamente \w y también p{L} El problema era que la entrada la estaba leyendo de un fichero de texto con un encoding diferente al que era y por eso no me estaba cogiendo los caractéres especiales.

Comment: De todas maneras la pregunta es interesante. Podrías editar tu pregunta y  responderte tu mismo.

Comment: Es además un buen ejemplo de algo que es específico del español, voy a editarla y respondo lo que sé sobre el tema

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Desafortunadamente no existe una categoría o un bloque o algo que pueda configurarse para un idioma en específico, puesto que cada uno de estos pueden compartir un conjunto de caracteres común, por ejemplo el [Basic Latin](http://bit.ly/1XZr7eV) es compartido entre el Español, el Inglés, el Frances, etc, más algunos caracteres propios.

Tratándose de letras únicamente:

- Español: `[a-zA-ZáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ]`
- Francés: `[a-zA-ZàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]`
- Alemán: `[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]`
- Italiano: `[a-zA-ZàèéìíîòóùúÀÈÉÌÍÎÒÓÙÚ]`

De acuerdo con [*Character Classes in Regular Expressions*](http://bit.ly/1XZrZQX), `\p{L}`es una categoría o bloque que encuentra cualquier carácter considerado como letra dentro Unicode, y `\w` incluye no solamente a las letras, sino además los dígitos, signos de puntuación y conectores (`_`).